# Ruby ffi gem issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

I installed `wpscan` - a Ruby programm for finding security issues on Wordpress sites. But when I tried to run it I got the following message:

```
[ERROR] dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/headius/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.1.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

My operating system is OS X Mavericks, but I don't have user with name `headius` and folder `.rvm`. I tried to reinstall `ffi` gem several times but nothing changed. I know that something wrong with `ffi_c.bundle` but this is a binary file and I don't know how to fix the path to `libruby.2.1.0.dylib` in it.

So, does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: headius is the nickname of Charles Nutter, the JRuby guy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bad FFI release (1.9.2) because it accidentally swept up my OS X bundle into the released gem. The 1.9.2 gem has been yanked and 1.9.3 replaces it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I installed ffi 1.9.3 and edited Gemfile.lock and now it works like a charm. I also reported about this issue to wpscan developers.