# Still error trying to run libtorch helloworld pod install on apple silicon m1

Tags: ios, ruby, pytorch, apple-m1

When trying to create the cocoapod for ios `pytorch helloworld` on my mac mini m1 (big sur 11.2.1)
with installed miniconda3, homebrew 3.1.1, ruby 3.0.1.p64, gem 3.2.15, pod 1.10.1
and PATH set to
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
according to [pod install giving error related to ruby gems and libffi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634792/pod-install-giving-error-related-to-ruby-gems-and-libffi)

running `pod install` dies with a segmentation fault, see the following ruby crash file
So maybe someone can give me an idea how to get ios 14.4 and m1 big sur 11  working together?

```
Process:               ruby [80736]
Path:                  /opt/homebrew/*/ruby
Identifier:            ruby
Version:               0
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [70856]
Responsible:           Terminal [70854]
User ID:               474179448

Date/Time:             2021-04-15 16:58:57.213 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5893C804-2FF8-FBB1-5889-A883C6E0135A

Sleep/Wake UUID:       0044F30E-9B3E-4B4D-B6D2-B508B271D6B1

Time Awake Since Boot: 85000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x1:
--> 
    __TEXT                      10234c000-102350000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /opt/homebrew/*

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185430cec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185461c24 pthread_kill + 292
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001853a9864 abort + 104
3   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026923a0 die + 12
4   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026923f8 rb_bug_for_fatal_signal + 88
5   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x0000000102774490 sigsegv + 96
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001854a9c44 _sigtramp + 56
7   ???                             0xffff80019719d8cc 0 + 18446603343051217100
8   libcurl.4.dylib                 0x000000019719d8cc curl_easy_getinfo + 40
9   libffi.dylib                    0x0000000191ef4050 ffi_call_SYSV + 80
10  libffi.dylib                    0x0000000191efc9d8 ffi_call_int + 944
11  ffi_c.bundle                    0x00000001042394cc rbffi_CallFunction + 260 (Call.c:400)
12  ffi_c.bundle                    0x000000010423d250 attached_method_invoke + 44 (MethodHandle.c:174)
13  libffi.dylib                    0x0000000191efce10 ffi_closure_SYSV_inner + 800
14  libffi.dylib                    0x0000000191ef41e8 ffi_closure_SYSV + 56
15  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e0b84 vm_call_cfunc_with_frame + 228
16  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027db078 vm_sendish + 1116
17  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027c7f70 vm_exec_core + 6948
18  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d72c8 rb_vm_exec + 1652
19  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e3df8 invoke_block_from_c_bh + 616
20  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d1bf4 rb_yield + 180
21  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026359a0 rb_ary_each + 84
22  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e0b84 vm_call_cfunc_with_frame + 228
23  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027db078 vm_sendish + 1116
24  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027c7f10 vm_exec_core + 6852
25  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d72c8 rb_vm_exec + 1652
26  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e3df8 invoke_block_from_c_bh + 616
27  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d1bf4 rb_yield + 180
28  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026359a0 rb_ary_each + 84
29  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e0b84 vm_call_cfunc_with_frame + 228
30  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027db078 vm_sendish + 1116
31  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027c7f10 vm_exec_core + 6852
32  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d72c8 rb_vm_exec + 1652
33  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e3df8 invoke_block_from_c_bh + 616
34  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d1bf4 rb_yield + 180
35  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x0000000102639ca8 rb_ary_collect + 168
36  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e0b84 vm_call_cfunc_with_frame + 228
37  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027db078 vm_sendish + 1116
38  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027c7f10 vm_exec_core + 6852
39  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d72c8 rb_vm_exec + 1652
40  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026dd2cc load_iseq_eval + 200
41  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026db528 rb_load_internal + 56
42  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001026dc850 rb_f_load + 180
43  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027e0b84 vm_call_cfunc_with_frame + 228
44  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027db078 vm_sendish + 1116
45  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027c7f70 vm_exec_core + 6948
46  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027d72c8 rb_vm_exec + 1652
47  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x0000000102698f8c rb_ec_exec_node + 268
48  libruby.3.0.dylib               0x0000000102698e20 ruby_run_node + 96
49  ruby                            0x000000010234fec0 main + 92
50  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018547df34 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185430e04 poll + 8
1   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027a9530 timer_pthread_fn + 124
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018546206c _pthread_start + 320
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018545cda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: FFI Callback Dispatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018542c488 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185462568 _pthread_cond_wait + 1192
2   ffi_c.bundle                    0x000000010423b80c async_cb_wait + 88 (Function.c:605)
3   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027a1c48 rb_nogvl + 280
4   ffi_c.bundle                    0x000000010423afa0 async_cb_event + 140 (Function.c:545)
5   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027a86b8 thread_start_func_2 + 1104
6   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027a8174 thread_start_func_1 + 152
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018546206c _pthread_start + 320
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018545cda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: open3.rb:403
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018542c488 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185462568 _pthread_cond_wait + 1192
2   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x000000010279f7b0 native_cond_timedwait + 120
3   libruby.3.0.dylib               0x00000001027a81e0 thread_start_func_1 + 260
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018546206c _pthread_start + 320
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018545cda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
...

Binary Images:
       0x10234c000 -        0x10234ffff +ruby (0) <F0E1ACB6-DADC-3709-A7C9-B20CA91730D9> /opt/homebrew/*/ruby
       0x1023ec000 -        0x1023effff +encdb.bundle (0) <0512F22A-C22F-3133-B7DF-C0630FBB7291> /opt/homebrew/*/encdb.bundle
       0x102400000 -        0x102403fff +transdb.bundle (0) <0749C9D7-559E-3089-8034-3F04F71589F5> /opt/homebrew/*/transdb.bundle
       0x102414000 -        0x102417fff +monitor.bundle (0) <46C2FFE4-EE5B-3C46-98D9-E6FE36564805> /opt/homebrew/*/monitor.bundle
       0x102428000 -        0x10242ffff +pathname.bundle (0) <52304C1D-6B1E-3CF4-927D-65D050FB8E7F> /opt/homebrew/*/pathname.bundle
       0x102440000 -        0x102443fff +escape.bundle (0) <80C6BFF1-ECCE-3004-96A4-3BC8A836F380> /opt/homebrew/*/escape.bundle
       0x102454000 -        0x102483fff +date_core.bundle (0) <5BEB2E2A-A969-3022-91F0-91F2A901D94B> /opt/homebrew/*/date_core.bundle
       0x1024a0000 -        0x1024affff +bigdecimal.bundle (0) <1292C18E-90FF-3113-A794-70FC5E7A61E6> /opt/homebrew/*/bigdecimal.bundle
       0x1024c0000 -        0x1024c7fff +stringio.bundle (0) <1A3F1181-6690-3E8C-BD5F-27F8A4A2F38D> /opt/homebrew/*/stringio.bundle
       0x1024d8000 -        0x1024dbfff +etc.bundle (0) <1E536D8B-A4A9-30F3-84E5-ADF950666B25> /opt/homebrew/*/etc.bundle
       0x1024ec000 -        0x1024effff +digest.bundle (0) <F596BA9F-A8BF-3D95-B5EB-6C617E4F0927> /opt/homebrew/*/digest.bundle
       0x102500000 -        0x102503fff +strscan.bundle (0) <9548F035-0164-3C07-A923-BE0DC07C4229> /opt/homebrew/*/strscan.bundle
       0x102514000 -        0x102517fff +wait.bundle (0) <AFC11C5F-E127-30EF-86C1-9DAD1B8027DA> /opt/homebrew/*/wait.bundle
       0x10252c000 -        0x1025a7fff  dyld (832.7.3) <4AB185B3-DC20-3C03-A193-67C0E6C589D7> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x102630000 -        0x10289bfff +libruby.3.0.dylib (0) <F87CC4ED-8475-3AEE-AD7B-2AF63B4EA539> /opt/homebrew/*/libruby.3.0.dylib
       0x103e1c000 -        0x103e3bfff +socket.bundle (0) <278655A9-7512-3AFC-AA68-6A824BA8C2FA> /opt/homebrew/*/socket.bundle
       0x103e54000 -        0x103e5ffff +zlib.bundle (0) <34A11F55-C4B0-3781-84CD-7847CC56B29E> /opt/homebrew/*/zlib.bundle
       0x103e74000 -        0x103e77fff +windows_31j.bundle (0) <610116E4-A042-3F9E-8CEF-0A0B4A608E4F> /opt/homebrew/*/windows_31j.bundle
       0x103e88000 -        0x103e8ffff +parser.bundle (0) <E08CB57E-FA0E-368E-8C2A-988494BD82A6> /opt/homebrew/*/parser.bundle
       0x103ea0000 -        0x103ea7fff +generator.bundle (0) <EA3FFFF6-797E-3172-9750-EFA602F9DA15> /opt/homebrew/*/generator.bundle
       0x103eb8000 -        0x103ef7fff +openssl.bundle (0) <D2ACCAC6-35B7-365D-A590-DC0A5683A383> /opt/homebrew/*/openssl.bundle
       0x103f24000 -        0x103f6ffff +libssl.1.1.dylib (0) <387D1B0F-EE36-3D80-96B0-21BCDA8B4E62> /opt/homebrew/*/libssl.1.1.dylib
       0x103fa4000 -        0x104123fff +libcrypto.1.1.dylib (0) <6703626D-9366-31E0-8697-C74FFA806779> /opt/homebrew/*/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
       0x1041c4000 -        0x1041c7fff +nonblock.bundle (0) <4285445A-338C-3B5F-9501-8132C66F1367> /opt/homebrew/*/nonblock.bundle
       0x1041d8000 -        0x1041dffff +psych.bundle (0) <6E68A386-AEB1-38A8-9AA3-4CB61FFA0439> /opt/homebrew/*/psych.bundle
       0x1041f0000 -        0x104207fff +libyaml-0.2.dylib (0) <86720355-4A4B-32E0-8BD0-18AB73A96463> /opt/homebrew/*/libyaml-0.2.dylib
       0x104218000 -        0x10421bfff +sha2.bundle (0) <F641AD10-D5E2-3D7D-BBFA-56F8294B442B> /opt/homebrew/*/sha2.bundle
       0x10422c000 -        0x104247fff +ffi_c.bundle (0) <6ADCB3BE-9056-33F0-AD30-10DAB38241E2> /opt/homebrew/*/ffi_c.bundle
       0x104270000 -        0x104277fff  libffi-trampolines.dylib (27) <ADFD2779-8444-3C1E-8AF1-F5BDCFDDA05B> /usr/lib/libffi-trampolines.dylib
       0x104280000 -        0x104283fff +sha1.bundle (0) <B63454E5-2319-352D-864B-8CEFF2C94880> /opt/homebrew/*/sha1.bundle
       0x1851be000 -        0x1851bffff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (78) <9B6D4883-03E9-3785-851E-EA79FA64ADC1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
       0x1851c0000 -        0x1851f7fff  libxpc.dylib (2038.80.3) <BD0DFD42-0DC3-3F3D-9C04-5A2B3D93794D> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
       0x1851f8000 -        0x18520ffff  libsystem_trace.dylib (1277.80.2) <4A466196-D2DD-367B-80AB-988F281EC3B8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
       0x185210000 -        0x185284fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (1000.80.5) <9BD8FED7-2A36-3602-A5A7-0CA87C03FB84> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
       0x185285000 -        0x1852b0fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (317.40.8) <21120432-52C1-34E4-BF01-623722FA3A41> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
       0x1852b1000 -        0x1852f4fff  libdispatch.dylib (1271.40.12) <F5BFBD55-EF70-3659-854D-9061325EB26D> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1852f5000 -        0x18532dfff  libobjc.A.dylib (818.2) <B03625B0-501E-3AC1-8E16-08B621120EAD> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x18532e000 -        0x185330fff  libsystem_featureflags.dylib (28.60.1) <297CC4DD-AFA4-3BA3-B4E1-0DF47E49C21E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
       0x185331000 -        0x1853b1fff  libsystem_c.dylib (1439.40.11) <A7147E08-E7C0-3842-916E-F2270A689F47> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x1853b2000 -        0x18540dfff  libc++.1.dylib (904.4) <B139607F-1E80-3A8E-870D-0AC022069EA1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
       0x18540e000 -        0x185427fff  libc++abi.dylib (904.4) <1DD3A1C9-D765-34FB-B8C1-87BF52CE49C0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
       0x185428000 -        0x18545afff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (7195.81.3) <55FCA547-4877-3075-8A08-FE1620BFC682> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x18545b000 -        0x185466fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (454.80.2) <8E907E6C-C227-312E-944C-767093692AFF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x185467000 -        0x1854a5fff  libdyld.dylib (832.7.3) <EF759BF3-97FA-30EA-A1CA-EDECFEA726FE> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
       0x1854a6000 -        0x1854acfff  libsystem_platform.dylib (254.80.2) <8633A39C-10A2-3B44-93F7-617AB09FF640> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x1854ad000 -        0x1854d8fff  libsystem_info.dylib (542.40.3) <4CC96CFC-7198-3F26-8C8C-20FB010CDF98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
       0x1854d9000 -        0x185982fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1774.101) <EA76C90A-23ED-3791-8FBC-8292916F0B16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x185983000 -        0x185bb5fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (1122.11 - 1122.11) <B79A592B-8036-3E24-AD9D-3FB4E7BE2983> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
       0x185bb6000 -        0x185c8efff  com.apple.gpusw.MetalTools (1.0 - 1) <ED9E3F77-4900-3B5B-978A-70AA6762DFBA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetalTools.framework/Versions/A/MetalTools
       0x185c8f000 -        0x185ee9fff  libBLAS.dylib (1336.40.1) <96EAD889-D898-3884-A36C-F433DC2C64DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
       0x185eea000 -        0x185f34fff  com.apple.Lexicon-framework (1.0 - 86.1) <81EA9F2C-6059-322A-B336-56CD7F3AB6C2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Versions/A/Lexicon
       0x185f35000 -        0x185f97fff  libSparse.dylib (106) <1A70E696-43E3-3D8B-A3E1-ADB624729BF4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
       0x185f98000 -        0x18601ffff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.20 - 1.20) <DD6AB615-BB7B-3634-9D33-3923E5038BAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
       0x186020000 -        0x186053fff  libCRFSuite.dylib (50) <79C1501B-B0F6-341A-96CC-F4FE066E3D59> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
       0x186054000 -        0x18627efff  libmecabra.dylib (929.1.1) <29B77781-FA91-3180-AFE8-608A355AE97E> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
       0x18627f000 -        0x186610fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1774.101) <8F7A0D5B-0E89-36F6-AC84-D3BEC2C44792> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
       0x186611000 -        0x186702fff  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 247.1) <66B05273-1979-3DB2-9F68-C0E3A6CD88B1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
       0x18728c000 -        0x1875eafff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 59754.80.3) <C76855AD-6EE4-3413-9E6E-CC450BDB20E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
       0x1875eb000 -        0x18785cfff  libicucore.A.dylib (66109) <3CE58F97-7FC3-37D8-BB99-D6BECFC86DD2> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
       0x18785d000 -        0x187867fff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1439.40.11) <B790A863-2D74-300E-9698-A25B5602B32F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
       0x187868000 -        0x187b57fff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1307 - 1307) <3EC22291-65E5-3EB6-9498-9A1244C90147> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
       0x187b93000 -        0x187bcefff  com.apple.CSStore (1122.11 - 1122.11) <52D8D7A1-4879-3488-9D39-5F2C7696EFA8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesStore
       0x187bcf000 -        0x187c99fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1845.81.1) <516911DA-18D7-3D17-8646-BBF7C75CD070> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
       0x187c9a000 -        0x187ca5fff  libsystem_notify.dylib (279.40.4) <A7B6BDA8-5371-352E-8A36-95D46C4B07F1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
       0x1890bc000 -        0x1897c6fff  libnetwork.dylib (2288.80.2) <07EC53A0-293C-3403-8394-755AE0BDDFA4> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
       0x1897c7000 -        0x189c54fff  com.apple.CFNetwork (1220.1 - 1220.1) <3C5F5D1E-DB7C-3027-BBB0-91E6DEA3E264> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
       0x189c55000 -        0x189c64fff  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (1295.80.3) <B6BD1267-BE59-3E42-B2B5-2BF13F17D02D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
       0x189c65000 -        0x189c66fff  libenergytrace.dylib (22) <C5CFEF87-BB69-3351-A0C8-9B601383A45C> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
       0x189c67000 -        0x189cbbfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib (978.80.1) <93C6E288-C098-357F-B8A5-3E133DF39ECE> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
       0x189cbc000 -        0x189cd3fff  libsystem_asl.dylib (385) <31E28E59-1CDD-3B83-8BF0-56C675227FA2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
       0x189cd4000 -        0x189cedfff  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <C55FE947-0C86-3AAC-9306-9EFA7C033D07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
       0x18aea2000 -        0x18aeb9fff  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 285.23.11.29.1) <38163CA8-14FF-34A9-8AE4-D7D69B8C8854> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
       0x18aeba000 -        0x18b061fff  libsqlite3.dylib (321.1) <8592B35B-9EA3-3C84-8453-9C86FB5C039C> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
       0x18b1c8000 -        0x18b23bfff  com.apple.AE (918.0.1 - 918.0.1) <7D13C9B5-D195-3E9E-B6C7-254F95A925C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
       0x18b23c000 -        0x18b243fff  libdns_services.dylib (1310.80.1) <64D4BA25-C388-3AB8-BDA8-2E81459DA46A> /usr/lib/libdns_services.dylib
       0x18b244000 -        0x18b24bfff  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (1431.40.36) <0657E539-C0CE-30F8-B630-FBAE36109542> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
       0x18b24c000 -        0x18b3a8fff  com.apple.Network (1.0 - 1) <486C55B3-900C-3D09-AB0D-F99A152CFB84> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Versions/A/Network
       0x18b3a9000 -        0x18b3cefff  com.apple.analyticsd (1.0 - 1) <E47FE17B-2ED2-3BE2-A5AB-046DB3C02EA0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/CoreAnalytics
       0x18b3cf000 -        0x18b3d1fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (112) <20AD555E-DF00-3C91-A95B-AB2AD23780AA> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
       0x18b3d2000 -        0x18b41dfff  com.apple.spotlight.metadata.utilities (1.0 - 2150.7.5) <5400DF7A-9249-30E9-B692-AC431C7F74D9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/Versions/A/MetadataUtilities
       0x18b41e000 -        0x18b4b7fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 2150.7.5) <4B03E6F8-1568-338B-AA75-480F9D824516> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
       0x18b4b8000 -        0x18b4befff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <7ED2211D-BA3C-37EC-BBA4-4320FBBC8A6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
       0x18b4bf000 -        0x18b7ddfff  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 544.2) <B1B84588-8B57-3F98-9D50-AAC142DFF36E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
       0x18bcda000 -        0x18bce7fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory (11.2 - 230.40.1) <C509DC91-F994-34B7-A5C5-A108E7DA5E4E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
       0x18bce8000 -        0x18bd07fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (11.2 - 230.40.1) <A5449895-6129-3BDF-864B-49ACA82E3052> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
       0x18bd08000 -        0x18bd10fff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1290.40.2 - 1290.40.2) <72CF142E-3792-318C-B2D6-B60C5E219312> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
       0x18bd11000 -        0x18bd35fff  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (144 - 144) <E4152CCC-4A03-3959-B788-D7DD1ADFF8A6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
       0x18bd36000 -        0x18bd38fff  libapp_launch_measurement.dylib (14.1) <A5637442-ADCB-30F0-AAB4-72FA1C5E3811> /usr/lib/libapp_launch_measurement.dylib
       0x18bd39000 -        0x18bd7cfff  com.apple.CoreAutoLayout (1.0 - 21.10.1) <6026D662-F75F-3C82-8C80-F6CEBF6369BF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework/Versions/A/CoreAutoLayout
       0x18bd7d000 -        0x18be68fff  libxml2.2.dylib (34.9) <E170FFEE-EB9F-3252-9B16-4A47FBAC425A> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
       0x18ccb9000 -        0x18cccafff  libsystem_containermanager.dylib (318.80.2) <0B742EA4-AFA2-36B6-AB4B-2F8ACA7211AA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
       0x18cccb000 -        0x18ccdcfff  com.apple.IOSurface (289.3 - 289.3) <64E3394D-C908-378C-B5CE-B89C6BE61E9F> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
       0x18ccdd000 -        0x18cce6fff  com.apple.IOAccelerator (439.52 - 439.52) <2995471C-4A7A-342A-B702-496519D138E2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
       0x18cce7000 -        0x18cdddfff  com.apple.Metal (244.32.7 - 244.32.7) <E8BC8E6D-4359-3A04-87CB-6F0D4F8F5C4B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
       0x18d8e4000 -        0x18d93bfff  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSCore (1.0 - 1) <F07355C4-C893-3534-B74E-DD5FBCBEC76C> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSCore.framework/Versions/A/MPSCore
       0x18d93c000 -        0x18d940fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (1109.60.2) <AEC5E654-A5B8-343E-80B7-27D5D0D856D9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
       0x18d941000 -        0x18d945fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (1441.60.4) <D7CDDE27-978E-3511-AE6F-296D901290B2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
       0x18d946000 -        0x18d947fff  com.apple.AggregateDictionary (1.0 - 1) <516D38F6-E0E1-36B4-AC96-E5079ECC6ED4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/Versions/A/AggregateDictionary
       0x18d948000 -        0x18d94bfff  com.apple.AppleSystemInfo (3.1.5 - 3.1.5) <E6509790-A434-3A6A-AF9E-EA1FDBF15F6A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
       0x18d94c000 -        0x18d94dfff  liblangid.dylib (136) <12979BA7-28E3-3E74-AC24-65166A921235> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
       0x18d94e000 -        0x18d9dcfff  com.apple.CoreNLP (1.0 - 245.1) <92E28F08-9AB8-3B02-A889-677A716E393C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/Versions/A/CoreNLP
       0x18d9dd000 -        0x18d9e4fff  com.apple.LinguisticData (1.0 - 399) <2B3E7B26-D669-38C0-9B7F-FFB2E94BC23B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinguisticData.framework/Versions/A/LinguisticData
       0x18d9e5000 -        0x18de9afff  libBNNS.dylib (288.80.1) <695BEB14-BA36-3386-8C72-A219A73C9601> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
       0x18de9b000 -        0x18df4dfff  libvDSP.dylib (760.40.6) <9FAC0A5B-0CD5-3999-815A-3C663EC71F65> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
       0x18df4e000 -        0x18df60fff  com.apple.CoreEmoji (1.0 - 128) <0FCD33E9-8DC4-3FB1-86DC-8ECA2FA10E37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/CoreEmoji
       0x18df61000 -        0x18df6bfff  com.apple.IOMobileFramebuffer (343.0.0 - 343.0.0) <57F4592F-D6FA-3ED9-ACEF-B1D7A7359DC1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/Versions/A/IOMobileFramebuffer
       0x18e26b000 -        0x18e2f0fff  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55240.40.4) <6D4E864F-4AAC-31AF-85AF-C308528C0F0B> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
       0x18e2f1000 -        0x18e2fafff  com.apple.coreservices.BackgroundTaskManagement (1.0 - 104) <8981AD5E-DC12-3B54-BAC0-E9E113C4B1A0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement
       0x18e2fb000 -        0x18e300fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <7B4325ED-9CF7-3D9E-A39C-F0AE7819F0C0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
       0x18e301000 -        0x18e303fff  libquarantine.dylib (119.40.2) <66942A5C-57B3-3524-BA49-0F2DA4A584D1> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
       0x18e304000 -        0x18e313fff  libCheckFix.dylib (31) <05E93C9D-45F9-3758-95FD-481E5EA2D5EF> /usr/lib/libCheckFix.dylib
       0x1913f9000 -        0x19140cfff  libsasl2.2.dylib (214) <D2C32F92-0728-3C67-B774-5CFC95F83497> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
       0x191cb4000 -        0x191cc4fff  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <862CCDF8-B5F2-3EDE-B728-B62CE0F158F7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
       0x191cc5000 -        0x191d0dfff  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <F4CC9D06-2046-3621-B654-96E7575115ED> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
       0x191d0e000 -        0x191d1dfff  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <DEE913BB-9741-3BB8-933A-64623CBCCC70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
       0x191eea000 -        0x191eeafff  liblaunch.dylib (2038.80.3) <327A64BF-8C2C-303D-91E4-70A168C5D87F> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
       0x191eec000 -        0x191efdfff  libffi.dylib (27) <92403FAB-6424-3AA3-ADB4-98FCD46D892A> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *ffi* has been fixed, I was able to successfully run `pod install`
without Rosetta

by running `sudo gem install ethon` with my homebrewn `gem` that installed `ethon-0.13.0`

and `sudo gem install ffi` that installed `ffi-1.15.0`

Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

You have to run CocoaPods in Rosetta mode:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Until this issue is closed: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907

Comment: Thanks for the good hint, alas now I get the next error
which seems like to be related to a missing ruby path, because the output refers to 
Ruby : ruby 2.6... which is not the homebrewn `which ruby`.
According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_environment_variables.htm
I have tried to set RUBYLIB - but without luck. Maybe you can tell me the proper env setting?

Comment: I have fixed a typo in the path to ruby gems, but the next error now is:
`arch: posix_spwanp: pod: Bad CPU type in executable`